# Using a GPIO pin as output and input

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

Good morning everyone,

i'm working in a project that involves having an state pin and button detection.

The escenario is the following:

- when raspberry pi finish booting, a pin is pulled HIGH (this is done via rc.local).
  That pin acts as "correct boot" state, and it will draw a little current (as it's powering a small circuit).
- when that pin is pulled to ground, via a push button, i want to execute a shutdown command.

The current code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

pinNum = 26

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pinNum, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
try:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(pinNum, GPIO.FALLING)
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
except:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The circuit hanging from that pin draws 0.2uA, which is not enough to trigger the edge detection, but, it eventually triggers the falling edge detection.

I'm working in the filtering of that circuit, as i suspect that is some AC oscillation or transient on that circuit that triggers that.
I'll post how the debbuging gets.

is there a more efficient/intelligent way to do this?

Regards,

Dani

Comment: pins, at any one time, can only be input OR output

Comment: I've read your post several times, but I cannot find a question. It should be possible what you want to do, but I don't know if your code will do it. Have you tried it? Did you get error messages?

Comment: The question is: how can i set a pin high being an input pin? (or turning it later to an input pin, but keep that high state)

Comment: by the way, you should look at overlay gpio-shutdown - you can then do shutdown and power up using GPIO 3

Comment: @JaromandaX you can read a pin that is set for output. At least that's what they keep telling me... Can't remember if I ever needed to do that.

Comment: See e.g. @joan's (short) response at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191954#p1203925

Comment: yes, you can read it, but the read value is whatever you write to it :p

Comment: I've just edited the question with the last advances i've made. The main point of the question is how to do this the most intelligent (and failsafe) way.

Comment: For the moment is working fine. As long as the current drawn from the pullup resistor is small enough, it can power a small circuit, and still be able to detect the falling edge. Next step is determining which is the maximum amount of current it takes to trigger the pin detection, and its tolerance (someone knows if this is documented somewhere?)

Comment: After thinking what the real question was for some time, here it goes: what's the current threshold that triggers a pullup resistor detection? and, can it be changed?